# how to json encode correctly in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i wanted to make the output look like this

```
[{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong"},
{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong"},
{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong"}]
```

but i really messed up with the code and the output 
this is my controller

`public function coa($id){
        $data['listcoa'] = $this->easyway_model->getCoa($id);
        $this->load->view('perusahaan_coa', $data);
    }`

and this is my model

```
    public function getCoa($id) 
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
          ->from('tb_coa')
          ->where('id_perusahaan', $id)
          ->get();
    return $query;
}
```

how should i call it in my view? so far i'm using foreach like this but the output really messed up

```
foreach($listcoa->result() as $list){
$cabang[] = $list->no_account;
$cabang[] = $list->deskripsi_coa;
$cabang[] = $list->tipe_akun;
$json = json_encode($cabang, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
echo $json; }
```

this is the output i get so far

```
{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong"}{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong","3":"1.1.001","4":"KAS","5":"kosong"}{"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong","3":"1.1.001","4":"KAS","5":"kosong","6":"1.1.002","7":"MANDIRI","8":"kosong"}
```

without the comma and the index of array keep increasing .

Comment: "really messed up" doesn't give us much to go on. Vague and/or opinion-based statements are almost always of zero use in the context of programming. What output did you get, instead of what you'd intended? Remember we don't know what data was used when you ran your code, so we can't see exactly what the result is going to be.

Comment: Also the code snippets are somewhat out of context. What is $listcoa and where did it come from? Where is $cabang first defined? The connection between the last bit of code and the earlier code is not obvious, and it seems incomplete.

Comment: i updated the output, my $listcoa came from the data in the controller. and the cabang[], somehow i really confuse with that just try to make an array and see the output though

Comment: Neither the output you produce now, nor the one you expect is not valid [JSON](http://json.org). Put all the data in an array and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) only once to encode the data stored in the array as [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: use this $json = json_encode($cabang, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);  out of the foreach loop

Comment: @axiac It is. Note that json_encode is run every time the foreach loops, so what we're seeing is the result of multiple executions of the command, with the object's contents obviously increasing each time as more data is added to the $cabang array.

Comment: @ADyson the question has been edited in the meantime. The expected output is valid JSON now but the code still produces multiple JSON strings. Concatenating JSONs doesn't produce JSON.

Comment: @axiac what I meant was that each individual piece of output is valid JSON. The fact it's all strung out on one line is simply a rendering issue. OP hasn't noticed the multiple outputs and is assuming it's all one object. That was my point.

Comment: @pradeep i tried to put the json_encode() outside the foreach but the output is something like this {"0":"1.1","1":"KAS & BANK","2":"kosong","3":"1.1.001","4":"KAS","5":"kosong","6":"1.1.002","7":"MANDIRI","8":"kosong",... }

Comment: @nothing see my answer, to make it an array instead of an object, remove the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You firstly need to move

```
$json = json_encode($cabang, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
echo $json;
```

outside your `foreach` loop. At the moment it's executing that command every time your loop runs, so you're outputting the `$cabang` array multiple times, and each time it contains more data, as the result of the latest loop is added.

You can also remove the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT setting if you want an array as the output, as per your question. And you need to make $cabang a multi-dimensional array.

```
$cabang = array();

foreach($listcoa->result() as $list){
  $item = array();
  $item[0] = $list->no_account;
  $item[1] = $list->deskripsi_coa;
  $item[2] = $list->tipe_akun;
  $cabang[] = $item;
}

$json = json_encode($cabang); 
echo $json;
```

Comment: wow thank you, tahnks a lot. it really work. another knowledge for me